# Cross-browser close tab event and ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom-events

How to implement cross-browser close tab event? I tried this:

```
function callAjax() {
 //some ajax stuffs for removing user from database
}

window.onunload = function() {
 callAjax();
 return null;
}
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
 callAjax();
 return null;
}
```

And it works, but if I quickly and many times push <kbd>F5</kbd> for refreshing page, ajax sometimes doesn't happen. Async is false.

Comment: You cannot rely on such events when it comes to managing sensible data. The user will always find a way to close a tab without your script knowing.

Comment: yep, but quickly refreshing is thing that someone can do by accident, twice or more

Comment: How has that anything to do with my comment?

Comment: You may have to consider using a service worker - which will detect the consecutive requests for your page assets in short time (not automatically - you will have to write some code) and then do something about that (on your choice).